# Trying to deploy a Spring Service on WSO2 Application Service

Tags: spring, web-services, wso2, apache-commons-logging, wso2-as

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Service in WSO2 Application Service. I did [THIS](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/) tutorial and the app works fine on Eclipse, but when I try to deploy it on WSO2 I get this error:

> Cannot load Spring beans. Please check the Spring context
>   configuration file and verify that the defined Spring beans exist in
>   the .jar file.

I unziped de `.jar` file and `JdbcCustomerDAO` class is there with all the others.

Spring context:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="customerDAO" class="com.mkyong.customer.dao.impl.JdbcCustomerDAO">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="url" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>     
</beans>
```

I also tried to include spring and mysql-connector-java jars on /repository/components/extensions as says [HERE](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS501/Spring+Services).

---

**EDIT:**

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.springservices.ui.SpringServiceMaker} -  Cannot
>   load Spring beans. Please check the Spring context configuration file
>   and verify that the defined Spring beans exist in the .jar file.
>   {org.wso2.carbon.springservices.ui.SpringServiceMaker}
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot
>   find class
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] for bean
>   with name 'dataSource' defined in resource loaded through InputStream;
>   nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource

Looks like it couldn't find spring-jdbc, so I added the `jar` to extensions but now I get this error:

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.springservices.ui.SpringServiceMaker} -  Cannot load 
>   Spring beans. Please check the Spring context configuration file and
>   verify that the defined Spring beans exist in the .jar file.
>   {org.wso2.carbon.springservices.ui.SpringServiceMaker}
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in resource loaded
>   through InputStream: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

I understand that commons.logging is also missing, but when I try to add it to extensions, WSO2 doesn't start. I get a lot of

> Log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate...

Comment: What is the application server version you used? check by adding mysql connector jar to repository/components/lib directory.

Comment: I'm using version 5.3.0 and I tried adding the connector there and I get the same error.

Comment: what is the class loading environment that you are using? Are you packing all the required jar in ur webapp?

Comment: What do you mean by class loading environment? I'm just adding the jar that Maven creates of my project. The problem is when I try to add the third-party libraries that my jar needs, commons.logging to be more specific.

Comment: I mean the class loading environment you mentioned in META-INF/webapp-classloading.xml of your webapp